# page visit every 50+ number url

Tags: php

i need to visit 50+ page 
example
`$page`=1 
`$page`=51
`$page`=101
`$page`=151

my php function visit `$page`=1 then `$page`=2 - can any help me?

```
function start(){
        $page=1;
        do{
            $ss=getpagecontent('http://www.domain.com/?pagenumber='.$page);
            for($i2=0, $i2Count=count($ss);$i2<$i2Count;$i2++){
                $jk=getDk($ss[$i2]);
                if(!saveDD($jk, $msg)){

                }
            }
            $page++;
        }while(!empty($ss));
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is increment `$page` by 50 each iteration. So you'd change this:

```
$page++;
```

To:

```
$page += 50;
```

Comment: An obvious solution... :P I don't think the OP knows very much php/C/C++

Answer (score 0):

```
function start(){
        $page=1;
        do{
            $ss=getpagecontent('http://www.domain.com/?pagenumber='.$page);
            for($i2=0, $i2Count=count($ss);$i2<$i2Count;$i2++){
                $jk=getDk($ss[$i2]);
                if(!saveDD($jk, $msg)){

                }
            }
            $page+=50;
        }while(!empty($ss));
    }
```